# Construct field Extension given that $\alpha$ has the following minimal polynomial

Tags: polynomials, extension-field

I apologize I have nothing to show that I have really attempted this question, but it's simply because I am struggling to get used to the terms and ideas.
I randomly chose a question from a past paper for my own practice and not very sure what the answer is.

> If $\alpha$ has the minimal polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$over $\mathbb{Q}$, construct the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

I suppose I am to solve the polynomial, to determine $\alpha$ but over $\mathbb{Q}$, I believe there is no solution. There are 4 distinct solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ though. So what exactly is $\alpha$ and how should I answer this question?

Comment: $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$. As you said, $\alpha$ must be a complex number. You need to specify the elements of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, which is the smallest field that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and a solution to the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ (that solution is $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like if you are struggling with the terms and ideas of field extensions and how polynomials are related to this, you should try reading a different source of explanation. Try reading [Chapter 21 from this book on abstract algebra](http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20130816.pdf). I know it's a 20-30 page chapter, but you don't necessarily need to read the whole chapter to learn about extension and splitting fields.

The most important thing you have to understand about $\alpha$ is that it's defined as one of the solutions to $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$. It's not a specific solution to that polynomial, since, as you pointed out, there are actually four different solutions, but $\alpha$ can be any one solution. Using that information, we have to construct our field extension.

Now, from the chapter above, you'll find that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the same thing as $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 \rangle$ with the isomorphism between them being the evaluation homomorphism. The important thing to notice about this is that this means that all elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ are in the form of $a\alpha^3+b\alpha^2+c\alpha+d$ for $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$. We never reach $\alpha^4$ because we know that since $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$, then $\alpha^4=-\alpha^3-\alpha^2-\alpha-1$, so we can just substitute $\alpha^4$ with lesser powers.

Now, two important properties about $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is if the field extension is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension) and if the field extension is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension). If the extension is separable, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ of degree $n$ has $4$ distinct roots. Now, in our case, this means that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ has $4$ distinct roots and none of them are repeated. As [@Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628333/construct-field-extension-given-that-alpha-has-the-following-minimial-polynom/1628346#1628346) wrote, the roots of this polynomial are all distinct roots of unity, which means that yes, this extension is separable. One handy thing to note is that **all** field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are separable because $\mathbb{Q}$ has a [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) of $0$. You can find a proof of this [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/perfect.pdf). (NOTE: I haven't verified this proof or read this whole document, but I have read other proofs of this and I know that it is true.)

We also need to find if this field extension is normal. If the field extension is normal, then this field extension is the [splitting field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field) of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, which is $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ in our case. This means that all of the roots of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is inside $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and that we don't need to add any more roots to fully factor the polynomial. Now, as [@Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628333/construct-field-extension-given-that-alpha-has-the-following-minimial-polynom/1628346#1628346) wrote, since all of the roots of this polynomial are roots of unity, we can generate the roots of unity with powers of $\alpha$ and factor this polynomial into linear factors as follows: $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)(x-\alpha^3)(x-\alpha^4)$. Thus, since $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ fully factors, this extension is normal.

Since the extension is both normal AND separable, it is a [Galois extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension) which means that it's really useful and has a lot of special properties.

I hope this explanation of this field extension helps you understand field extensions better!

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your generous answer to my question. I haven't learned up to normal or seperable extensions yet but I hopefully will get a hold of it coming back to this answer in future.

Comment: I'm glad my answer could help!

Answer (score 1):

The solution are the non-real fifth roots of unity: $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2\mathrm i k\pi}5}$. Any of these roots is a power of any other root (this is because $5$ is prime), so $\alpha$ can be any of these values.

As $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbf Q$, and its minimal polynomial is $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, the extension is simply
$$\mathbf Q(\alpha)=\mathbf Q[\alpha]\simeq \mathbf Q[x]/(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1),$$
so that it is made up of the polynomials in $\alpha$, of degree $\le 3$. As the other roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, are powers of  $\alpha$, the extension is normal, and, as we're in characteristic $0$, is a Galois extension of degree $4$.

Comment: That explains how to find $\alpha$, but it doesn't explain how to construct the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Is the extension normal? Is the extension separable? I think those are the kinds of things they are trying to find.

Comment: Separable in characteristic shouldn't be a question, in my opinion. I'll add some details for the rest.

Comment: This person said that he was having some trouble understanding the concept of an extension field, so he might not understand that all extensions in fields of characteristic 0 are separable. In my answer that I'm writing now, I'm going to link him to a proof of this so hopefully, all of our answers together will help him understand.

Answer (score 1):

The abstract algebra approach is to verify that $p(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, and then construct the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$. [Note that being irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to $p(x)$ being irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.]

The "value" of $\alpha$ can then be identified with residue class of $x$ in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$.

This turns out to be isomorphic to the ring extension $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ that "lives" inside the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.  Since $p(x)$ is irreducible, the quotient ring is an integral domain, and the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to the quotient field of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$.